# Java and Spring back-end with Ruby (RhoMobile) front-end security

Tags: java, spring-security, rhomobile, shiro

I am currently building a mobile application using RhoMobile. The application will simply be calling a bunch of REST web services. The back-end REST services are written in Java + Spring. I was wondering what the security considerations are. Our requirements are very simple, we need a secure way for a user to log in with the application, and only then be able to call the web services.

Does anyone have any experience with marrying these technologies. And what are my options. At the moment I am looking at either using Spring Security or Shiro, but just wondering if anyone has better experience.

Just as a note, we will be using JSON for all communication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have my backend web server running a Ruby On Rails application.
I communicate using JSON and HTTP Basic Authentication. In this type of authentication it is needed only to pass a header with the user name and the password encoded.
It is not the best way to achieve security, because if someone is monitoring your network traffic he could discover your credentials, but it could be a simple solution.

Comment: We are considering BASIC over HTTPS, but definitely **not** over HTTP. Way too insecure. And we would store the credentials in the payload, not the header, so that it is encrypted.